# Wayland with Intel Graphics results in graphical stuttering - is there a solution?

Tags: graphics, video, intel-graphics

I've been using wayland with intel 520 graphics and, for the most part, it works excellently. However, I noticed that any hardware accelerated 1080p video playback (VLC,MPV etc) causes stuttering, not just in the video, but on the entire desktop (for instance, pressing super to see programs side by side with be stuttery).

I also noticed that, unlike with XORG, when video is playing played, the graphics card only reports "Render" being used, not "Video":

[image: picture of odd GPU usage]

Is there any solution to this problem? I am eager to say on wayland because so many other things work well (touch screen, mouse gestures etc). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best thing you can do is [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121).  Bug reports are not accepted on Ask Ubuntu so it's not productive to report them here. Bugs can't get fixed without bug reports!  In the meantime, I would just continue to use X.org until the bugs with Wayland are sorted out.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise this was a bug! I assumed it was my error.

Comment: I can't imagine that anyone would consider it a feature or setting ;)

Comment: I will do as you suggest Nmath! Thank you for your help